# Get the value of an Excel Option Box using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to use c# to open an existing excel file, read value of an existing option button (true/false) and write the value to anther cell.

I can open the file just fine, but I'm stuck on how to get the value of the option button.  The option box is a form control not an activeX control.

The code below works until the last line and then it generates a COMexception.

```
Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();  //creates the application
xlApp.Visible = true;

string wbPath = @"C:\path.xlsx";
Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wbPath,
    0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);
//opens the specific file

Excel.Sheets xlS = xlWb.Worksheets;
string currentSheet = "1";
Excel.Worksheet xlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)xlS.get_Item(currentSheet);

Excel.OptionButton opt1 = (Excel.OptionButton)xlWS.OptionButtons(1);
```

I am pretty new to programing.  Any help or resource would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Thanks OmegaMan for the push in the right direction.  I'll post the code here in case anyone with a similar problem needs the help.

```
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();  //creates the application
        xlApp.Visible = true;   //change to false for final version

        string wbPath = @"C:\path.xlsx"; //sets the path
        Excel.Workbook xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(wbPath,
            0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
            true, false, 0, true, false, false);
        //creates the workbook and opens the specific file

        Excel.Worksheet xlWS = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWb.ActiveSheet;   //sets the active sheet

        Excel.Range gr1Text = xlWS.get_Range("e20"); 
        Excel.Range xlRngP19 = xlWS.get_Range("p19");
        Excel.Range xlRngQ19 = xlWS.get_Range("q19");
        xlRngP19.Value = gr1Text;

        string[] rating = { "Exceptional", "Demonstrates skill level necessary for position", "Needs Improvement", "N/A" };

        bool opt1;
        opt1 = xlApp.ActiveSheet.OptionButton2.Value;
        bool opt2;
        opt2 = xlApp.ActiveSheet.OptionButton1.Value;
        bool opt3;
        opt3 = xlApp.ActiveSheet.OptionButton3.Value;
        bool opt4;
        opt4 = xlApp.ActiveSheet.OptionButton4.Value;
        bool chBox1;
        chBox1 = xlApp.ActiveSheet.CheckBox1.Value;


        Excel.Range xlRngP20 = xlWS.get_Range("p20");

        if (opt1 == true)
        {
            xlRngP20.Value = rating[0];
        }
        else if (opt2 == true)
        {
            xlRngP20.Value = rating[1];
        }
        else if (opt3 == true)
        {
            xlRngP20.Value = rating[2];
        }
        else if (opt4 == true)
        {
            xlRngP20.Value = rating[3];
        }
        else 
        {
            xlRngP20.Value = "**NOT RECORDED**";
        }

        if (chBox1 == true)
        {
            xlRngQ19.Value = "Growth Opportunity";
        }


        xlWb.Close(true);
        xlApp.Quit();
        //closes the file
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the secrets of the interop programming for the office programs is to create a macro of the desired operation. Once saved look at the VB code which calls differing interop methods. Those methods are the same ones you will have to deal with in your C# program.

If nothing else it helps you research the operations needed which may lead to other ways of programming it.

In Excel the developers tab is not shown by default, you will need to turn it on to do the macro and run the VB editor.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  I'm working with vba now.  Any idea on why the last line is generating a COM exemption?

Comment: @akb put in a try catch, then edit your post to add the actual com exception to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for sharing Akb. And here's how to set the value:

```
if (job == "Y")
{
  ((Excel.OptionButton)gma.OptionButtons("jobYes")).Value = true;
}
else
{
 ((Excel.OptionButton)gma.OptionButtons("jobNo")).Value = true;
}
```